# CSS Clear after every nth-child

Tags: html, css

I have multiple items with same width inside a container. Because of different heights of the elements, there is problem with the alignment, you can see in image below.

I want to clear after every 3rd item **without changing the html** markup, so that the 4th item goes to the next row. I'm trying to add nth-child(3):after, but does not seem to work.

[image]

Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item:nth-child(3):after{
    content: "."; 
    display: block; 
    height: 0; 
    clear: both; 
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/KPXyw/

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Actually it's

```
.item:nth-child(3n+1){
    clear:left
}
```

Comment: As long as they all have the class of `.item`. Otherwise `.list div:nth-child(3n+1)` or just `.list :nth-child(3n+1)`.

Answer (score 7):

```
.item:nth-child(3n+1){
    clear:left
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KPXyw/4/)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `nth-child(3n+1)` so that it happens at *each* child following a child multiple by 3, not only at the first 3rd child.

Then, you should remove that `:after`, you want to clear the actual child.

Answer (score 1):

[sabof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/735243/sabof) is right. But It will be great if you use `display: inline-block` instead of `float:left`. Please see below for example.

```css
.list {
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: yellow;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this its working

```
.list{
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item{
   float: left;
    width: 90px;
    background: yellow;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item:nth-child(4){
    //background: brown;
    clear:both;
}
```

these only need.

Comment: It is not working if you have more lines filled in with `.item`s. This is because you specified `4` in the `nth-child` rule, which applies **only** and just only for the fourth element.

Comment: i tried with more items and it worked, thats why i post the answer. It may be of the width of item(width is specified for .item).Whatever it is it worked for this question.I posted the answer of this particular question not for general.And you are also right a accept that.

Comment: Maybe the `.list` width is not specified, that's why in your case it works because other `.item`s don't have room to be displayed on the same row, hence they are moved on the next one. Have you tried modifying the `.list` width to, say, 500px?

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
.list {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  ...
}
```

See below:

```css
.list {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  float: left;
  width: 90px;
  background: yellow;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
  background: brown;
}
.item:nth-child(3):after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use below code

```
.item:nth-child(4){clear:both;}
```

Comment: To explain why this will not work: If you clear after every 4th element, it would throw off the 3 column grid, as the 8th .item is not the first element in the second row, but the second. This is why you use 3n+1. It takes every third element and increments one. Here is a great article on how this math works. http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/