# What is the equivalent of JSTL <c:forTokens> in JSF or PrimeFaces?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jstl

Assume we have the following JSP code:

```
<c:forTokens items="${someBean.aStringOfIntNumbersSeparatedBySemicolons}" 
             delims=";" 
             var="item" 
             varStatus="stat">
  ${item}
  <c:if test="${!stat.last}">;</c:if>
  <c:if test="${stat.count %5 == 0}">
    <br/>
  </c:if>
</c:forTokens>
```

Of which the output is rendered in rows with 5 columns each, like so:

[image]

How can I possibly do this with the JSF or Primefaces tags?

Comment: You can use those core tags in JSF, xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
Otherwise just use ui:repeat and compute the var attribute with a custom function like <ui:repeat value="#{custom:split(tokens)}">

Comment: @Mick I tried but I can't use the `<c:forTokens>` tag of `${...}` expressions along with JSF. It won't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent, you should transform your token into a list in the managed bean and consume the list in the framework components.

```
List<String> tokens = Arrays.asList("car1,car2,car3,car4".split(","));
```

For such simple scenario you might not need the primefaces components. When you go for a Object Oriented model, you can take advantage of PF components to iterate through the list and present its fields using data binding. For instance:

**DataList** - For each Car type in the cars1 list, a line will be added in the list.

```
<p:dataList value="#{dataListView.cars1}" var="car" type="ordered">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Basic
    </f:facet>
    #{car.brand}, #{car.year}
</p:dataList>
```

[image]
**DataTable** - For each car in cars list, a row is added to the table component.

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtBasicView.cars}">
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Color">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

[image]

Using such [component framework](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/) you might speed your development focusing on the business logic instead of UI design.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013925/css-clear-after-every-nth-child...

Answer (score -1):

#### The only working solution I've found

For now, the only working solution I've found lies partly in the JSF and partly in the back-end code:

1. Edit the back-end code so that it adds a `<br/>` after every fifth element of that `String` field `aStringOfIntNumbersSeparatedBySemicolons`.
2. Add `escape="false"` to the `<h:outputText>` tag that holds the data on the front end. (The default value is `escape="true"`, which renders `<br/>` as `&lt;br/&gt;`)

Comment: Sorry, but this is very 'un-web-like' solution. You could easily use the splitting as done in the upvoted answer and then use a `ui:repeat` to render divs and use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013925/css-clear-after-every-nth-child...